# Metasploit & openvas error (openvas_connect)

Tags: metasploit, openvas

I'm using Kali 4.3.0 and trying to run openVAS plugin into the Metasploit. OpenVAS (version 8.0) works properly on port 9392, metasploit is ok too. This is log of error:

```
msf > openvas_connect admin admin 127.0.0.1 9392 ok
[*] Connecting to OpenVAS instance at 127.0.0.1:9392 with username admin...
[-] Error while running command openvas_connect: OpenVAS OMP: Error in OMP request/response

Call stack:
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/openvas/openvas-omp.rb:110:in `rescue in sendrecv'
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/openvas/openvas-omp.rb:100:in `sendrecv'
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/openvas/openvas-omp.rb:178:in `auth_request_xml'
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/openvas/openvas-omp.rb:251:in `login'
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/openvas/openvas-omp.rb:132:in `initialize'
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/plugins/openvas.rb:192:in `new'
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/plugins/openvas.rb:192:in `cmd_openvas_connect'
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/rex/ui/text/dispatcher_shell.rb:427:in `run_command'
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/rex/ui/text/dispatcher_shell.rb:389:in `block in run_single'
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/rex/ui/text/dispatcher_shell.rb:383:in `each'
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/rex/ui/text/dispatcher_shell.rb:383:in `run_single'
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/rex/ui/text/shell.rb:203:in `run'
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework/command/console.rb:48:in `start'
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework/command/base.rb:82:in `start'
/usr/bin/msfconsole:48:in `<main>'
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Password is correct, the problem is not in auth

Comment: check status of OpenVAS Manager.
`#services openvas-manager status | stop | start | restart`

Comment: @schroeder 'openvas-manager' and 'openvas-scanner' are both active

Comment: and OpenVAS and MSF are fully updated?

Comment: Probably running on IPv4 localhost port 9390

Answer (score 3):

Don't Connect to 9392. Instead Connect to 9390

> openvas_connect username password localhost 9390 ok

Answer (score 0):

There is no more OpenVas API that can connect to Metasploit so you can't connect to it.

Port 9392 is a fallback port for Greenbone Web Server if port 80 is not available.