# openVAS: uninitialized constant OpenVASOMP::OMPConnectionError

Tags: metasploit, openvas

I was searching in many forums regarding this issue like [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/123451/metasploit-openvas-error-openvas-connect) and [here](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?18550-Metasploit-starting-issue), but they were mentioning using port 9390. I launched OpenVAS on port 9390, but I still get the same error.

I am using `openVAS` in `msfconsole` on Kali Linux. I load `openVAS` successfully, but when I try to connect, it shows me this error.

```
  openvas_connect root toor 127.0.0.1 9390
    [*] Connecting to OpenVAS instance at 127.0.0.1:9390 with username root...
    [-] Error while running command openvas_connect: uninitialized constant OpenVASOMP::OMPConnectionError

    Call stack:
    /usr/share/metasploit-framework/plugins/openvas.rb:195:in `rescue in cmd_openvas_connect'
    /usr/share/metasploit-framework/plugins/openvas.rb:189:in `cmd_openvas_connect'
    /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/rex/ui/text/dispatcher_shell.rb:501:in `run_command'
    /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/rex/ui/text/dispatcher_shell.rb:453:in `block in run_single'
    /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/rex/ui/text/dispatcher_shell.rb:447:in `each'
    /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/rex/ui/text/dispatcher_shell.rb:447:in `run_single'
    /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/rex/ui/text/shell.rb:151:in `run'
    /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework/command/console.rb:48:in `start'
    /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework/command/base.rb:82:in `start'
    /usr/bin/msfconsole:49:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What port did you start OpenVAS on?

Comment: @schroeder I started on port 9390. I have already changing it to different ports like 9392.

Comment: Questions about internal errors of programs are things to ask the vendor/developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer for this is to reinstall the whole configuration and start over again due to missing dependencies:

```
root@kali:~# apt-get --purge autoremove openvas
root@kali:~# apt-get update
root@kali:~# apt-get dist-upgrade

root@kali:~# apt-get install openvas
root@kali:~# openvas-setup
```

Once openvas-setup completes its installation process, make sure that OpenVAS manager, scanner, and redis-server services should be running.

```
root@kali:~# /etc/init.d/openvas-manager status 
root@kali:~# /etc/init.d/openvas-scanner status 
root@kali:~# /etc/init.d/redis-server status
```

Then you can simply start all the necessary services by running `openvas-start`. Then run your browser to `https://127.0.0.1:9392`, and accept the self signed SSL certificate and plugin the credentials for the admin user